# Apache basic auth: Why am I getting "HTTP 401 Invalid credential" with correct credentials?

Tags: apache-http-server, authentication

I have these settings in my vhost conf file:

```
  <Location / >
    AuthType Basic
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
    AuthName "Please log in with your Apache username and password"
    Require valid-user
 </Location>
```

But when I go to the site and enter the correct credentials, I get a blank page saying only "HTTP 401 Invalid credential".

I am certain that the credentials are correct, for two reasons:

1. When I type in nonsense credentials, the authentication popup comes back, prompting me to try again. But with the correct ones it does not.
2. When I try with nonsense credentials I see a message in the access log saying "user foo not found". But I do not see this with the correct credentials.

What could cause this problem? I have SSL redirects going on, I wonder could this affect it? Please let me know if I can supply any more information to help you answer the question. Thanks!

**EDIT: By grepping for "Invalid credential" I've just discovered the problem is caused by CiviCRM, by the Authx extension. Have accepted the answer which led me on the way to finding this out.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you are getting 401 not because of invalid credentials, but because you are trying to access something not permitted: folder without index.html, and `Options +Indexes` not configured.

Try to remove authentication and repeat the same request. Or try to request specified file, like `/favicon.ico`

As for message `HTTP 401 Invalid credential`, I believe you added it by yourself, because default error page shows something along the lines

```
Authentication required! or Unauthorized!
This server could not verify that you are authorized...
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! When I remove authentication the site works perfectly. I am not sure where the error message is coming from but yes I agree it is not standard.

Comment: I just spent some time looking to that error message, and discovered that it is coming from civicrm! So that's what I need to look into. I just wanted to let you know that you helped me to find the problem.